# Process builder

Tags: salesforce, apex, processbuilder

I created Contact Change event in Process Builder
Object: Contact
Criteria: Lastname change
Action: Apex
Here i am sending changed to contact id to my invocable apex class method
From that method i am creating an task for that Contact Change as an Activity with complete status
But there is Set Schedule section, i didn't configure for this section and i activated this Flow
I try to change my contact lastname as a new value but this trigger not working
Is it Set schedule section is necessary to trigger this workflow?
Or can i remove this option from workflow because i dont need that section.
I didn't see this Set Schedule section in workflow before, is it added as new one?
Can you suggest how to resolve this without Set schedule option?